# How to fix android build error - Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, android, gradle, jvm, android-build

Hi I am trying to build Android apk and I get the following errors when I run the shell script.

Could you suggest what I can do to resolve this please.

I have latest JAVA installed

```
xx.xxx@OEMBP01 app-android % java -version
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Error I get is

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=GB -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp 

    /Users/xx.xxx/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.1.1-all/1wqbeia0d49252rmlcr6o8lbl/gradle-7.1.1/lib/gradle-launcher-7.1.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 7.1.1
    Please read the following process output to find out more:
    -----------------------
    Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m'
    Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
    Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
    
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using two JVM options that are no longer available in recent Java versions:

- The `MaxPermSize` option [has been removed in Java 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8-compatibility-guide.html)
- The `UseConcMarkSweepGC` option [was deprecated in Java 9](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/291)

Both options were initially reported as a warning and now raise an actual error when trying to start the VM.

Unless you encounter specific issues, you should be able to rely on the current default values, so simply remove `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` and `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` from your list of arguments (e.g. in your `gradle.properties` file).

Comment: Question might be: did the OP actually put that somewhere, or where exactly is it coming from ;-)

Comment: Hello thanks for your response, where should I remove XX:MaxPermSize from?

Comment: I can see that as part of the gradle.properties file
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

Comment: Yes, remove it from there then. You might need to remove the `+UseConcMarkSweepGC` option as well (if that comes up as next error). That one was deprecated in Java 9.

Comment: I have removed it and now I get an error Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
is UseConcMarkSweepGC required?

Comment: Please read my previous comment again. I have also updated my answer - both options are no longer required.